# Selecting a Group of records based on a single Record Value

Tags: mysql, database

Let us consider we I have a table as follows

[image]

I need to select the records with same "group_id" s where at least anyone record's "type" is equal to 1.

The expected result set must be like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
select * from table where group_id in
(
    select group_id from table where type = 1
)
```

You can also try `join` instead of `in`

```
select a.* from table a
join 
(
   select group_id from table where type = 1
) b on b.group_id = a.group_id
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a single query without any inner query??

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I don't think you can achieve this using the id instead of group_id but if you think it's possible, please post it as an answer.

Comment: "I don't think you can achieve this using the id instead of group_id " your right, i need some coffee not awake